# scroll with scripty2

Tags: javascript, scripty2

how can you scroll with scripty2??

```
document.body.scrollTo(300, {
    transition: 'easeInOutQuad',
    duration: 0.5
});
```

have also tried with window.scrollTo()

EDIT: 
this doesnt work either

```
$(document.body).scrollTo(300, {
    transition: 'easeInOutQuad',
    duration: 0.5
});
```

but in some other code this works fine

```
this.loader.morph('opacity:1; filter:aplha(opacity=100)', {
    transition: 'easeInOutQuad',
    duration: 0.5
});
```

Comment: Googling `scripty2 scroll` gives me this: http://scripty2.com/doc/scripty2%20fx/element.html#scrollto-instance_method

Comment: yes, I have tried that..

Comment: Show the code you have tried.

Comment: Ah. You can't run scripty functions on DOM elements - you need to turn them into Scripty elements first. See below.

Comment: By the way, please don't delete and re-post questions. Edit them to bump them instead.

Comment: Doesn't look like it - scripty is fairly new, and I see very few questions (and answers) around. Is there a specific reason why you want to use it over jQuery? As far as I can judge, jQuery has become top dog among JavaScript frameworks.

Comment: has jQuery good smooth equations to animate elements? I thought scripty2 was quite known?

Comment: I'm fairly sure jQuery has what you need. See http://api.jquery.com/animate/ and http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Comment: I just stumpled over scripty2's nice animation equations..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.body` is not automatically a scripty element. You need to either turn it into one, IIRC like so:

```
$(document.body).scrollTo(.......);
```

or use `Element.scrollTo`:

```
Element.scrollTo(document.body, .....);
```

Comment: but isnt $() only to transform element ids to an element object?

Comment: @clarkk no, it should be possible to transform a DOM node as well: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/